# How to set htaccess when putting CodeIgniter into existing site

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, migrate

I looked for the answer, and was surprised I couldn't find this specific situation:

I have an existing "straight" PHP site at http://www.mysites.com/site1/ and want to migrate it to CodeIgniter over time. I know there are a few ways to do this, but I'd like to leave the existing site alone and just put the CodeIgniter folder (CI) in the root directory (site1), then redirect requests to it if the file or directory doesn't exist.

So this .htaccess file is in the site1 folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /site1/CI/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and this .htaccess file is in the site1/CI folder (needed?):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and the CodeIgniter config.php file contains:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.mysites.com/site1/CI/';
```

This works fine if I try to go to a location on the existing site (e.g., http://www.mysites.com/site1/page.php), but if I try to go to a page that should be routed to CodeIgniter (e.g., http://www.mysites.com/site1/home), I get a 404 error from CodeIgniter. It appears to be looking for method 'home' in controller 'site1' instead of controller 'home'.

So I then tried this .htaccess file in the root directory to get rid of 'site1' being passed to index.php:

```
RewriteBase /site1/CI/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|assets)
RewriteRule /site1/(?:(.*)) index.php/$1 [L]
```

Unfortunately, that caused Apache to return a 404.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got everything working for putting a CI application inside an existing site one folder level deep. Here is how I did it.

Folder structure used:

- site1

  - page1.php
  - page2.php
  - etc...
  - CI

    - application
    - assets
    - system
- site2
- site3

.htaccess in site1 folder:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond $1 !^(images|robots\.txt|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ CI/index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 ^assets
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ CI/$1 [L]
```

Note that I took the usual "index.php" out of the third RewriteCond in the first block (because of HybridAuth and CodeIgniter routing described below). The second block is to redirect CodeIgniter page asset folder references to the assets folder inside the CI folder. (Otherwise I'd have to move the assets folder to the site1 folder.)

This is the base url in the config.php file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.mysites.com/site1/';
```

I had to add the following to the routes.php file inside the CI config folder:

```
$route['site1/index\.php/(:any)'] = "$1";
$route['site1/(:any)'] = "$1";
```

Even after the Apache redirect, CI still sees "site1" in the URI and, therefore, try to load the "site1" controller which obviously doesn't exist! The *second* $route[] takes "site1" away.

I'm also using HybridAuth which includes "index.php" in its callbacks, so CI will see it in the URI and try to load the "index.php" controller which obviously doesn't exist either! The *first* $route[] takes "site1/index.php" away.

Hopes this helps someone.